# Saving to 3 decimal places using QueryNew and QuerySetCell in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Coldfusion 9

I have this query:

```
<cfset final_standings_table = QueryNew("p_final_standing_id,f_group_id,win,loss,tie,points,win_loss_per,games_played,f_division_id,str_division,str_group_name,str_group_url,score","CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_DECIMAL,CF_SQL_DECIMAL,CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_INTEGER,CF_SQL_VARCHAR,CF_SQL_VARCHAR,CF_SQL_VARCHAR,CF_SQL_INTEGER")>
```

See (CF_SQL_DECIMAL) in the 7th position (win_loss_per)

My client wants three decimal places, but when I try to record the calculation

```
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(final_standings_table, "win_loss_per", "#evaluate((total_wins + total_ties) / games_played)#", fml_row_count)>
```

I can only seem to get it to two decimal places.

Comment: Use CF_SQL_FLOAT , also look at NumberFormat function if you want 3 decimal places.

Comment: CF_SQL_FLOAT doesn't seem to be in cf9 for querynew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno what is going on with your code / values, but the number of decimal places your values end up with has nothing to do with `querySetCell()` or that you're putting the data into a query at all.

This code demonstates it's no problem to have more than two decimal places:

```
q = queryNew("data", "Decimal");
queryAddRow(q);
querySetCell(q, "data", pi());
writeDump(q);
```

This results in `3.141592653589793` being in the query. If you want to truncate that to 3DP, then use `numberFormat()` to do so.

So you need to give us more info about what's going on if this is not working for you.

Can you provide some self-contain, completely stand-alone code which demonstrates the problem?  IE: a repro case.

Comment: Never mind. I found the issue. It wasnt my query of query. Basically when I was looping over that qofq and inserting it into the db, I didnt use cfqueryparam to set the scale so it defaulted to 2.